# Recommended approach for updating a table (sheet) based on values from another table (sheet)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have three sheets structured in table format: (A) Raw Data, (B) Processed Data, (C) Edit View. They are connected as shown in the below diagram.

[sheet structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7dmI.png)

The black arrows are already complete (using apps script to aggregate data from raw to processed, and to display processed data in an edit view). What I'm struggling with is the blue: updating (A) Raw Data from what I have entered in (C) Edit View.

What is the recommended approach for accomplishing the update? My initial thought was to use an 'UPDATE' statement similar in SQL but that doesn't seem to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered writing a script with onEdit(e) {}

Comment: Thanks for your input, Stefan. I'm not too concerned with the trigger as I already have one in mind, the user will change all the data that they need to in (C) Edit View and then press 'Submit'.

What I'm still unsure of is the approach with the script that makes the edit...

Comment: Via a script you can delete the data in A and replace it with C. If you know for sure C is the same range or larger then you can simply overwrite.

Comment: C is a filtered range so it will be scattered throughout A. In addition, C is an 'aggregate' view of A (which is what B was for).

i.e. C is a filtered view aggregated by weeks/months. A is the raw data by day.

Comment: Do you have a unique ID for the data in A that is pushed through to C?

Comment: Unique ID would be a concatenation of [Source] + [Name] + [Date]. Example: Forecast + John Smith + Feb 6, 2018

Comment: This would in theory make it possible to write a script that updates A based on changes in C. Formulas won't help you for they won't allow changes and it would also create a loop that isn't allowed.